# Shell script result output to a file

Tags: shell

I just faced a problem about shell script output problem. Here is the code

```
read_each_user_rating(){
TOTAL_RATING_NUMBER="$(grep -c '<Author>' $1)" #Find how many rating in each file
ALL_AUTHOR="$(grep '<Author>' $1 | sed -e 's/<Author>//'| tr -d '\r')"
ALL_COMMENT="$(grep '<Content>' $1 | sed -e 's/<Content>//'| tr -d '\r')"
ALL_DATE="$(grep '<Date>' $1 | sed -e 's/<Date>//'| tr -d '\r')"
ALL_RATING_FILE="$(grep '<Overall>' $1 | sed -e 's/<Overall>//'| tr -d '\r')"
ALL_VALUE="$(grep '<Value>' $1 | sed -e 's/<Value>//'| tr -d '\r')"
ALL_ROOMS="$(grep '<Rooms>' $1 | sed -e 's/<Rooms>//'| tr -d '\r')"
ALL_LOCATION="$(grep '<Location>' $1 | sed -e 's/<Location>//'| tr -d '\r')"
ALL_CLEANLINESS="$(grep '<Cleanliness>' $1 | sed -e 's/<Cleanliness>//'| tr -d '\r')"
ALL_CHECKIN="$(grep '<Check in / front desk>' $1 | sed -e 's/<Check in / front desk>//'| tr -d '\r')"
ALL_SERVICE="$(grep '<Service>' $1 | sed -e 's/<Service>//'| tr -d '\r')"
ALL_BUSSINESS="$(grep '<Bussiness service>' $1 | sed -e 's/<Bussiness service>//'| tr -d '\r')"
for ((COUNTER_A=1;COUNTER_A<=$TOTAL_RATING_NUMBER;COUNTER_A++))
do
echo "INSERT INTO UserRating (Author,Comment,Date,Overall,Value,Rooms,Locations,Cleanliness,Checkin,Service,Bussiness)" >> hotelreviews.sql
echo $($ALL_AUTHOR | sed "${COUNTER_A}q;d") >> hotelreviews.sql
done
}
read_each_user_rating $1
```

I can output
     echo "INSERT INTO UserRating (Author,Comment,Date,Overall,Value,Rooms,Locations,Cleanliness,Checkin,Service,Bussiness)" >> hotelreviews.sql to the file. But why i can output "echo $($ALL_AUTHOR | sed "${COUNTER_A}q;d") >> hotelreviews.sql" part to file too?

Comment: What do you expect? What actually happens? At a guess I'm assuming you need to escape some of your `$`s.

Comment: The `grep | sed` part of each line can be replaced with just `sed -n -e 's/<Whatever>//p'`, which will only print the lines where a replacement could be made.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $($ALL_AUTHOR | sed "${COUNTER_A}q;d") >> hotelreviews.sql
```

is malformed. The expression inside `$()` must be a valid command (of which `$ALL_AUTHOR` is almost certainly not).

More likely you need something such as:

```
echo "$ALL_AUTHOR" | sed "${COUNTER_A}q;d"
```

inside the `$()`.

In this case however, it's almost certainly not necessary to invoke a sub-command *at all* when you can simply do:

```
echo "$ALL_AUTHOR" | sed "${COUNTER_A}q;d" >>hotelreviews.sql
```